# Copying a sublist into a main list as objects instead of lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x, copy

```
child = []
parent = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
index = 2
child.append(parent[:index])
```

When I have this code run, instead of returning me a child list of

```
child = [1, 3]
```

I get a child list of:

```
child = [[1, 3]]
```

Is there a single line method of copying a few objects of a list into another list without making it into a nested list?

Comment: Briefly: use `extend` rather than `append`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
child.extend(parent[:index])
```